# google map marker don't work in chrome and IE

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-markers

I have create a zoom to fit markers Google maps
and it works well in Firefox but not in chrome and IE

the problem in chrome and IE all marker are the same.

you can see the code source in this link

http://www.ermes.net/user/profile/zoommap.php?user_id=40442

Comment: What versions of Chrome and IE you are using? Also, try isolating your actual problem from the complete source code. Right now, the question is very specific to your problem in hand and won't help future visitors of stackoverflow.com that much.

Answer (score 0):

all i see is these 2 lines of code. you use the same icon in all your markers

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker( latlng,getIcon_StrRicettive());  
//var marker=new google.maps.Marker( latlng,getIcon_Comunita());
```

i didn't check all the source code, but the lines i checked had the same "duplicate" code